Branch PR policies - any way to exclude the wiki?
In our master branch I have a policy of mandatory PR, linked work items etc. I'd like to exclude the wiki folder since, for us, it's ok for any member of the team to change as needed.
Is there way to do that? My research came up empty (and ChatGTP is worse than useless in this case).
TIA
Jim

You mean for builds configured in the "Build Validation" section?

Hi @RuiJarimba no, although a build is annoying it's not a problem. The problem (for us) is that direct commits are not allowed: "Require a minimum number of reviewers" is 1, so you have to go through a PR, which (again for us) doesn't make sense for the wiki part.

Got it. I honestly think that all changes should be reviewed (including documentation/wikis), but if your team has agreed not to do it that's fine.

No. Only build validation policies may exclude or include paths. Consider moving your wiki to a separate repo then you may publish it as an additional wiki component:


I think this workaround is the best idea. Thanks!
